# ¿porque mi consulta mysql desde python se devuelve asi?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

Esta es mi consulta desde python

```
consulta ="SELECT nombre FROM usuario WHERE id= '123'"
```

y me devuelve:

```
(('Jose Perez',),)
```

y en la tabla esta:

```
nombre       id
Jose Perez   123
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por que lo que recibes es una estructura rectangular de filas y columnas que se definen como [tuplas](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), en tu ejemplo estás recibiendo una fila con una sola columna, es decir

```
(
  ('Jose Perez',),  # Fila 1
)
```

Si fueran más las filas y las columnas, seguramente sería más clara la idea:

```
(
  (123, 'Jose Perez',),  # Fila 1
  (124, 'Luis Gomez',),  # Fila 2
)
```

Si necesitas extraer, por ejemplo el nombre, es decir el dato de la fila 1 y columna 1, puedes hacer:

```
t = (
  ('Jose Perez',),  # Fila 1
)
nombre = t[0][0]
```

Comment: Entiendo, entonces ¿deberia recuperar todo el objeto y luego extraer el nombre?

Comment: @NatanJimenez, exactamente. Revisa mi última edición,

Comment: en efecto funcionò gracias! por la explicacion y el tiempo

Answer (score 1):

Es debido a que el ORM(mapeo objeto-relacional o más conocido como Object-Relational mapping) de python trabaja como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: ORM Python]

- Teniendo el modelo del lado Izquierdo y las clases creadas por python del otro lado.

El ORM que estes usando... funciona como un puente entre los Objetos de la base de datos y los Objetos Python, en pocas palabras hace un mapeo:

- Clase -> Tabla
- Atributo -> Columna
- Objeto -> Fila

Comment: En ese caso. Yo deberia pedir todos lo resgistros? o como podria para solo obtener el nombre en cuestio?